# Why am I getting the error message "operator cannot be applied to operands of type string and int"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I'd like to make a pagination system, so I have made a general class for that in where I'd like to retrieve the values of page and size parameters of url but it doesn't work , I get this message :

> operator cannot be applied to operands of type string and int

this is the code:

```
    // http://localhost:6289/api/Customer?page=3&size=3

    public static IQueryable<T> Paginate<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        var queryParams = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
        
        string page = queryParams.Get("page");
        var size = queryParams.Get("size");
     
        return source.Skip((page - 1) * size).Take(size);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `page` is a string, the exception is telling you that you can't subtract a number from a string.

Comment: It's also a terrible idea to start accessing the HttpContext all over your code. You'll just end up with a tangle of magic strings. Read it when the API is invoked then pass the parameter around

Comment: @DavidG page is the name of parameter witch  is a string ?so how to get it's value

Comment: `string page`..page is a string

Comment: @Liam "It's also a terrible idea to start accessing the HttpContext all over your code" I'm beginner what do you suggest ? because in my code I have webApi project, and ServiceLayer project and DataLayer project. if I pass the parameters inside the function in the controller I must pass them to ServiceLayer and from ServiceLayer I pass them to DataLayer. they give me this conception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clicking game - Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545709/clicking-game-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-string-and)

Comment: Well I'd say your making the classic inexperienced mistake. There is more than [one architecture](https://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns) and in fact I'd argue quite strongly that a [3 layer architecture is an anti-pattern](https://devmethodologies.blogspot.com/2012/10/the-layer-anti-pattern.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert string **page** and **size**  to int. Try like:

```
 string page = queryParams.Get("page");
 int p = int.Parse(page);
 int s = int.Parse(size);
 return source.Skip((p- 1) * s).Take(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the get parameters from string to integers.

Try this:

```
int page, size;
if (Int32.TryParse(queryParams.Get("page"),out page) && 
    Int32.TryParse(queryParams.Get("size"),out size)) {
        return source.Skip((page - 1) * size).Take(size);
} 
else {
    // return 404 of some such in case of non-integer input
}
```